# How to send QuickSight report as an email?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have created multiple reports in QuickSight and Whenever I have the requirement to share the report with anyone I need to log in and add his/her name in IAM to create login and link to share the reports.

I searched the internet but didn't find anything that I can use to share the QuickSight Report as an email not even in QuickSight paid Training. I believe the feature is not available as of now but my question is - Is there any alternative to share/Send QuickSight report as an email?

Comment: Now in quickSight there is an option to share.
QuickSight Report --> dashboard --> share (enter email addresses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you published the Quicksight Dashboard,

Do the following steps

a) Open the required dashboard page from "Dashboards Section"

b) You will see the option to Share & e-mail the Dashboard report to the respective users

[Dashboards Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR3zw.png)

c) Once you click the share via e-mail. You will see the following page to select options to select the required users and frequency of the email reports to be sent automatically.

[Email reports page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwuh0.png)

Comment: Thanks, Dev, I was about to answer my question last Thursday.
Currently, it is available for Enterprise user Only. I hope it will be available for all user soon.

Comment: Agreed. We mapped our costs & If one has more than 10 Users, Enterprise version seems cheaper than other. Do comment if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can give access to Quiksight by following ways :

Signing In as a New User Using Credentials Based on Your Email Address :

- Sign in as a new user who has an account based on an email address
- Signing In as a New User Using Your IAM Credentials
- Self-Provisioning an Amazon QuickSight user
- Self-Provisioning an Amazon QuickSight administrator

You can refer to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/request-access.html)
Alternatively what you can do is export the report as PDF or Excel and send email of it.

Thanks